# Unable to boot/install after nvidia drivers install

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

Installed ubuntu 17.10 3 days ago and all was fine, till I updated my Nvidia drivers. Afterwards my laptop wouldn't boot properly and got into a kernel crisis. I tried to reinstall ubuntu, but to no use. I completely wiped my harddrive in the hope that would help, still not solved.

I ran boot-repair-disk and added the text file with this post. Hopefully someone can help me out on how to get ubuntu installed again.

Thanks in advance!

```
Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 8200 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

Invalid MBR Signature found.


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 2 GiB, 2130689536 bytes, 4161503 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048     4,161,502     4,159,455   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sdb1        4CA0-3C2E                              vfat       BOOT-REPAIR
/dev/zram0       5ded3a06-6fbb-4563-8253-9d4decb985c4   swap       
/dev/zram1       ee405afd-b1d9-4f4e-a350-874c3033d215   swap       
/dev/zram2       59e71f61-792b-48b0-8353-19d063b10416   swap       
/dev/zram3       db210668-1720-4507-aae1-a6783ec2340b   swap       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  6 18:05 ata-Crucial_CT256MX100SSD1_14440DAC5F98 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  6 18:03 ata-TSSTcorp_DVD+_-RW_TS-L633J_R8126GEB848775 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  6 18:05 usb-GENERIC_USB_MASS_STORAGE_Storage_2010-0412154148-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec  6 18:05 usb-GENERIC_USB_MASS_STORAGE_Storage_2010-0412154148-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  6 18:05 wwn-0x500a07510dac5f98 -> ../../sda

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Boot-Repair-Disk session" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 20171206_1805 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa62
boot-sav version : 4ppa62
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa62
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa4
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 1oct2017, zesty, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
ls: cannot access '/home/usr/.config': No such file or directory

=================== os-prober:


=================== blkid:
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="BOOT-REPAIR" UUID="4CA0-3C2E" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00012cf6-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/zram0: UUID="5ded3a06-6fbb-4563-8253-9d4decb985c4" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram1: UUID="ee405afd-b1d9-4f4e-a350-874c3033d215" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram2: UUID="59e71f61-792b-48b0-8353-19d063b10416" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram3: UUID="db210668-1720-4507-aae1-a6783ec2340b" TYPE="swap"


=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:



=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:256GB:scsi:512:4096:unknown:ATA Crucial_CT256MX1:;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:2131MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:GENERIC USB MASS STORAGE:;
1:1049kB:2131MB:2130MB:fat32::boot, lba;

BYT;
/dev/zram3:504MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:504MB:504MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

BYT;
/dev/zram1:504MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:504MB:504MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

BYT;
/dev/zram2:504MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:504MB:504MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

BYT;
/dev/zram0:504MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:504MB:504MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL
loop0 loop squashfs 629.3M
sda   disk          238.5G
sdb   disk              2G
sdb1  part vfat         2G BOOT-REPAIR
sr0   rom            1024M
zram0 disk          480.2M
zram1 disk          480.2M
zram2 disk          480.2M
zram3 disk          480.2M

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs
sda      0  0  0 running
sdb      1  0  1 running
sdb1     1  0  1         /cdrom
sr0      1  0  1 running
zram0    0  0  0         [SWAP]
zram1    0  0  0         [SWAP]
zram2    0  0  0         [SWAP]
zram3    0  0  0         [SWAP]


=================== mount:
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1939828k,nr_inodes=484957,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=393404k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=//filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=15432)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/999 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=393400k,mode=700,uid=999,gid=999)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=999,group_id=999)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro sdb1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight integrity power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri drm_dp_aux0 dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fb1 fd freefall full fuse hpet hugepages hwrng i2c-0 i2c-1 i2c-10 i2c-11 i2c-12 i2c-13 i2c-14 i2c-15 i2c-16 i2c-17 i2c-18 i2c-2 i2c-3 i2c-4 i2c-5 i2c-6 i2c-7 i2c-8 i2c-9 initctl input kmsg kvm lightnvm log mapper mcelog media0 mei0 mem memory_bandwidth mqueue net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sdb sdb1 sg0 sg1 sg2 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uhid uinput urandom userio v4l vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net vhost-vsock video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     385M   40M  345M  11% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat      2.0G  708M  1.3G  35% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  630M  630M     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   1.9G  1.3G  608M  69% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     385M  4.0K  385M   1% /run/user/999

=================== fdisk -l:
Disk /dev/loop0: 629.3 MiB, 659873792 bytes, 1288816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes




Disk /dev/sdb: 2 GiB, 2130689536 bytes, 4161503 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00012cf6

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 4161502 4159455   2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/zram0: 480.2 MiB, 503558144 bytes, 122939 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram1: 480.2 MiB, 503558144 bytes, 122939 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram2: 480.2 MiB, 503558144 bytes, 122939 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/zram3: 480.2 MiB, 503558144 bytes, 122939 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Error: no partitions

** (zenity:6065): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.


=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  repair-filesystems


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.
```